# Jacobian transpose times a vector

Tags: derivatives, jacobian, transpose

It is possible to evaluate Jacobian times a vector:

$$ J v = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{ f(x + \epsilon v) - f(x) } {\epsilon }$$

Is it possible to calculate $ J^T v$ and $ J^T J v$ in similar fashion?

Comment: did you mean $Jf(v), J^Tf(v)$ and $J^TJf(v)$?

Comment: I mean Jacobian of f(x) (i.e J matrix) times a vector v.

Answer (score 2):

There is no similar formula for $J^T v$. For example consider the case when $f\colon\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, then $J$ is $1\times n$ and so $J^T v$ is just a scalar multiple of $J^T$.

This is the reason why for example transpose free iterative methods are so important for things like large scale Newton methods, cf. chapter 7.4 in *Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems* by Yousef Saad

Comment: Thanks, what about least square problems where Jacobian transpose is necessary, specially when Jacobian is rectangular.

Comment: @Hesam I am not aware at which point in the least squares problem $\hat\beta = \arg\min \|y-X\beta\|_2^2$ one needs to compute a product between a Jacobian transpose and a vector. One needs to compute $X^T X \beta$, but $X$ is not the Jacobian.

Comment: I meant nonlinear LSE like: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

What you can say is that $J(x)^T v$ is the gradient of $\phi(x) := f(x)^T v$. Therefore,
$$
(J(x)^T v)_i = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(f(x + h e_i) - f(x))^T v}{h},
$$
where $e_i$ is the $i$-th column of the identity matrix.